# Stop drag and down functionality

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet in which there is drop down functionality having data validation now i want user not to drag down value instead i want the user should filled value one by one.Is there a way by using app script i can prevent the user in doing so or there is any alternative for the same by which i can achieve the same

I have make another sheet in that sheet i have imported original sheet but what happens whenever i update anything in that range it throws reference error

Cell should get change whenever user update anything in imported sheet or is there a way we can do something different similar to this for achieving the functionality

Comment: Could you please provide a public, sanitized copy of the sheet you're working on? I don't think I fully understand the problem you're having.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "i have importe original sheet". Do you do this by using a formula, a script or manually?

Comment: i did this by using formula or is there a way by which i can override import range functionality by using app script

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets and Google Apps Script haven't a way to disable drag and drop and haven't a way to know how the user is adding a value to a cell.

Regarding an alternative, I found weird that you getting a reference error as they usually occurs when a formula is copied/pasted from one position to another where the reference can't be recalculated, i.e., if on B1 you have =A1, (one cell to the left) and copy/paste this formula to A1 it will throw the #REF! error because there isn't one cell to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it isn't possible to disable the drag and drop functionality in Google Sheets without also disabling the ability to edit the cell's contents. Protecting ranges of cells

There are a few workarounds depending on your implementation however:-

- Create a Google form which the user can submit answer to and have it
  populate the sheet with the answers
- Create a web HTML-based form which has individual input boxes that can not be dragged and dropped. Using this you could also disable copy + paste functionality using JavaScript, if users cheating to write the same value multiple times is the issue you're trying to avoid.